# Play multi part video without interrupts (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I want to split a video into parts, but play it in the browser as a single video. In my inital attempt I split the video with ffmpeg and used the onended event to play the next part. The disadvantage is that it interrupts before the next part is started. Also, it's not possible anymore to use the built in controls for seeking.

Therefore, I am wondering if it's possible to split the video into chunks of a certain size, load always only the current chunk and avoid the interrupts somehow. The perfect solution would be if I could implement my own stream or blob type which loads the chunks asynchronously.

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? with HTML5 the browser (user agent) is able to use byterange requests to be fairly intelligent about bandwidth usage so, in conjunction with the the preload attribute you should be able to avoid splitting the file. Any home grown solution (eg toggling two elements) is going to require a lot of work to manage seeking etc properly

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, what I forgot to mention is that the parts are spread over several servers. I know that it is a strange setup, but in this special case I cannot prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is the MediaSource API: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API
Unfortunately, only Chrome supports it yet.