# Term for web video split into many chunks transparently to the user

Tags: html, http, video-streaming, html5-video, terminology

I notice (by looking at the Chromium network tab) an annoying phenomenon of many Web sites that include videos implementing video playing by sending many small video chunks, with the user (behind the Web browser) not aware of this and even being capable of seeking through the video and seeing the current "position" in the video's reproduction relative to the start and end.

What is the professional term/jargon used for this?

Some existing questions that talk about or mention such Web videos:

[Play multi part video without interrupts (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250154/play-multi-part-video-without-interrupts-html5)

[Chunk audio/video files for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894859/chunk-audio-video-files-for-web)

[Are html5 streamed videos cacheable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306334/are-html5-streamed-videos-cacheable)

[videojs: Download/stream video in chunks with quality selecton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598081/videojs-download-stream-video-in-chunks-with-quality-selecton)

[How does video on demand work in Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679586/how-does-video-on-demand-work-in-youtube)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term your probably looking for is “Adaptive Streaming” or “Adaptive Bitrate Streaming”. Or maybe you are looking for names of implementations like “DASH” or “HTTP Live Streaming”

Also, it’s not an “annoying phenomenon” it’s a technique that allows for live streaming media with an undetermined length that can adjust to each users internet connection without using expensive media servers and can leverage existing CDNs and caching infrastructure.

Comment: Nice! Who would have thought Youtube and Netflix actually stream video according to a standard.

Comment: By the way, things like "Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP" are annoying when one wants to download/save a (whole) video for storage. Of course there are programs that do that for specific sites, but what if the target site is not supported? Then what could have been a simple curl command turns into a programming problem.

Comment: The sites that implement this don’t care about that use case. In fact, making download harder is often a bonus. Also if a tool does not support a site, just write a new tool.